# Cannot install windows 10 alongside Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, dualboot

I have Ubuntu installed on my NVMe drive on my computer. I wanted to install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu. I followed tutorials and when I boot from the USB stick which has Windows 10 on it and go through the steps I cannot install it on the disk which has Ubuntu installed as it gives an error although in the tutorials I saw online it worked fine. Here is the error that appears:
[image]

I went into the installation log file and I cannot know what is causing the issue, here is the contents of the [log file](https://pasteall.org/ay9p)

Comment: Which partition is Ubuntu on (ext4) and where do you want to install Windows? Possibly the Windows installer won't install to unallocated space, and needs an NTFS partition. Of course, first backup anything of interest on Ubuntu side, in case something goes wrong.

Comment: @user3169 No, the Windows installer can perfectly install it in any sufficient unallocated space and it's actually the preferred scenario as it allows the creation of more than one partition. NOT the problem here but keep reading for a better understanding of possible scenarios that may prevent such installation ->

Comment: @ChanganAuto any advice how to fix the problem?

Comment: @Tak (1) In what mode was Ubuntu installed? For a dual-boot you need to boot and install the second OS in the same mode, UEFI (preferred) or Legacy/CSM/"BIOS". (2) What is the partitioning type of the drive where you intend to install Windows, MBR or GPT? Unlike Ubuntu which is flexible, Windows strictly requires GPT for UEFI mode and MBR for Legacy. If you have Ubuntu installed in the proper UEFI mode but with the old MBR partitioning you won't be able to install Windows there, period. Please [edit] the question and describe what you have as commented here.

Comment: @ChanganAuto 1- it is installed in Legacy cause if I change to UEFI mode my NVMe drive is not readable and doesn’t appear in the boot list only network ports appear I don’t know why? Is there a way to have my NVMe drive readable in UEFI? 2- I am not sure, how I would know this? It’s NTFS and even if I choose format in the screenshot in my question and format the partition I still get the same error.

Comment: NVMe drives actually prefer UEFI/GPT. Using Legacy with NVMe or in any 10 years old or newer machine is a mistake and usually the start of many problems (like this one, probably). For Windows, again, you want UEFI mode and GPT; For Ubuntu and considering the dual-boot scenario it's the exact same requirement PLUS the drive mode as AHCI ("RAID" or Intel RST aren't (yet) supported). This is probably why the Ubuntu installer wasn't seeing it.

Comment: Your installed Ubuntu works, right? If so you can open Disks, select the target drive and it'll tell whether it is MBR ("msdos") or GPT. Then adjust your expectations accordingly.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if MBR, even if you manage to boot the Windows media in Legacy mode, you WON'T be able to install it because MBR has a limit of 4 primary partitions (GPT has no such problem). This is why you should ALWAYS choose UEFI mode AND GPT (unless installing an a very old, pre-2012, computer).

Comment: @ChanganAuto It’s a new Dell tower workstation. Do you have any advice on how to make my NVMe drive readable in UEFI mode?

Comment: Sure, advice already given. In a more detailed way you should enable UEFI, disable Legacy/CSM -and- **change the drive mode to AHCI** (because Ubuntu; Windows can be installed with either mode). There's nothing else. This are basic stuff you need to be familiar with, no exceptions, if you intend to have a dual-boot. Unfortunately Youtube videos seldom mention all this details and many are just for clicks and "likes" and show a Virtualbox installation which doesn't reflect the method needed for any bare metal installation in a UEFI machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135340/discussion-between-tak-and-changanauto).